# Django postgresql on Heroku DatabaseError value too long for type character varying(1000)

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, django-postgresql

I'm getting this error when saving a Django Model Object:

> DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(1000)

Inside the model there is a textfield:

```
models.TextField()
```

I'm saving a string of over 1000 characters into this field (song lyrics). The webapp works when run locally, which also uses postgresql, but generates this error when deployed on Heroku

Is there a hard limit on Heroku's postgresql or is there a way to increase it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely not a hard limit on PostgreSQL.  The question is how best to lift the limit.  Ideally you'd probably do it in Django I assume instead of `ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar TYPE varchar;`

Comment: Can you post your models.py with this model and the view or code that is inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. When I cleared all migration and tried migrating again, it worked.